# Как вывести в консоль пайтон папки(фалы в этих папках) и файлы в директории

Tags: python-3.x, ос

Вот код но он не рабочий.

```
from os import *
for i in listdir("."):
    try: print(listdir(i))
    except: print(i)
```

Comment: `import glob` `glob.glob('*')` ?

Comment: Чем он не рабочий-то?

Comment: @andreymal потому что он получает строковое имя папки, а не путь к ней, и не может получить содержимое.

Comment: @Alban у меня этот код прекрасно работает, содержимое папок успешно получает. В данном случае строковое имя папки эквивалентно пути к ней

Comment: @andreymal только в данном случаи

Comment: Все пацаны напичатал код рабочий

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx4SSBRC-o5ybTdGVVRmNzVMOHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Alban а про другие случаи в вопросе ничего не говорится)

Answer (score 0):

[os.scandir](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/),
[os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir),
[os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk),
[pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#path.glob),
[glob.iglob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob)

```
import os

# os.scandir
def subdirs(path=os.getcwd()):
    """Yield directory names not starting with '.' under given path."""
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_dir():
            yield entry.name

# os.listdir
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    print(i)

# os.walk
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    print(root, "consumes", end="")
    print(sum([os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name)) for name in files]), end="")
    print("bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files")


# pathlib.Path
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path('.')
for i in path.glob('*'):
    print(i)


# glob.iglob
import glob
for i in glob.iglob('*'):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Надо бы первый пример в функцию обернуть :)